# Why does Drools re-evaluate and re-trigger rule actions after a persistent session is reloaded?

Tags: drools

I have a simple rule like the one below:

```
package rules

dialect "mvel"

declare MyEvent
  @role( event )
  @expires( 2d )
  id String
  value: Double
end

rule "My Rule"
  when
      MyEvent($value : value)
  then
    System.out.println("My event with value: " + $value);
end
```

I create a persistent session and call `fireAllRules()` on it. Then, I insert a `MyEvent` fact, and as expected the rule is evaluated, matched and the action is executed. If I call `fireAllRules()` again the rule is not matched, as expected because it has already matched for the same fact. At this point everything is fine.

Then I kill the JVM and run the app again. At startup the app loads the session like this:

`kieSession = kieServices.getStoreServices().loadKieSession(KIE_SESSION_ID, kieBase, kieSessionConfiguration, kieEnvironment);`

The session gets loaded successfully, and then `fireAllRules()` is called again. Since the rule has already matched for the inserted event, I am expecting that it does not match again. However I can see the message in the rule action is printed again. Why does Drools match the rule for the same eventagaian? To me it looks like the session state is not properly saved to database. I mean, the event is saved, but Drools can not recogonize that it has already matched the rule. When I load a persistent session I expect to recover exactly the same state that the session had in the previous running instance. Is my assumption wrong? or Am I doing something wrong for the expected behaviour?

Running:
JavaSE 11
SpringBoot 2.3
Drools 7.53.0

Comment: Are you sure that the session is properly persisted and retained through the restart? and that your changes pre-restart are persisted as well (so the persisted state is up to date)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I think so. If the session does not exist I create it with `kieSession = kieServices.getStoreServices().newKieSession(kieBase, kieSessionConfiguration, kieEnvironment);`. From ahead I use that session and I can see that the timestamp in `sessioninfo.lastmodificationdate` table column is updated when the fact is inserted and also everytime rules are fired:

Comment: Snapshot of the sessioninfo table after the session is created
id|lastmodificationdate   |rulesbytearray|startdate              |optlock|  
1|2021-10-29 11:28:00.051|         26475|2021-10-29 11:27:36.663|      2|  
 
 
Snapshot of the sessioninfo table after the event is inserted and before rules are fired
1|2021-10-29 11:28:38.799|         26477|2021-10-29 11:27:36.663|      4|
 
 
Snapshot of the sessioninfo table after rules are fired 
1|2021-10-29 11:29:04.205|         26478|2021-10-29 11:27:36.663|      5|